# How To Show Keyboard When UIAlert Present Which The UIAlert With Custom UITextLabel View

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uialertview, uialertcontroller

How to show keyboard when `UIAlertController` is present with Custom View and `UITextField`? I mean I want to keyboard automatically show without user touch the `UITextField` in alert view.

My code like below to make a Alert.

```
func callAlertConfirmation() {
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 70)

    let textBookmark = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 230, height: 40))
    textBookmark.placeholder = "Typing folder name"
    textBookmark.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textBookmark.textColor = UIColor.black
    textBookmark.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textBookmark.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    textBookmark.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
    textBookmark.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    textBookmark.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    textBookmark.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    textBookmark.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    vc.view.addSubview(textBookmark)

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create New Folder", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.setValue(vc, forKey: "contentViewController")

    let actOKButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        // action When User Okay
    }
    alert.addAction(actOKButton)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.preferredAction = actOKButton
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

And when I call

> callAlertConfirmation

I get the result like this picture:
[image]

But I want to picture like below when I call

> callAlertConfirmation

[image]

But when I use

> alert.addTextField

I get keyboard automatically show when alert present.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: uialertcontroller is not meant to be customized , you can use uiview to customize and show it as alert.

Comment: This is because alert controller doesnt know about the view you have added. Try calling `textBookmark.becomeFirstResponder()` to get the focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What**

As @C4747N already said, you need to call

```
.becomeFirstResponder()
```

**When**

You want to call this method as you present the alert:

```
present(alert, animated: true) {
    textBookmark.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

The way you want to "read" this is like:

> Present the alert and once you're done execute the completion body (make the alert's textField first responder)

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but whenever I want a UITextView or UITextField to show a keyboard immediately i do:

```
textBookmark.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Thanks, but must add Solve with DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            textBookmark.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
And put this code after present.
Thanks.

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { textBookmark.becomeFirstResponder() } is not a good way to solve this issue. You had this issue because you are trying to make textBookmark first responder, but its superview (alert) is not presented yet. To solve this, you want to call becomeFirstResponder() method in the present's completion block!